# Malformed relay? Outputs current from NO when no signal is passed

Tags: relay

I'm using [this](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/file/view/SLA-05VDC-SL-C_Datasheet.pdf/577719703/SLA-05VDC-SL-C_Datasheet.pdf) (SLA-05VDC-SL-C) relay.
After about 40 minutes of usage (with [this](http://www.ebay.com/itm/371020458305) module) at ~10A turing the relay off via the module seems to turn it off (click is sound and the red light turns off) but, the NO leg still outputs current at ~196V when the input is ~230V (NC is obviously ~230V).
Only after 1-2 days the NO stops outputting any current.

Is the relay malformed?
No reason for it to behave this way right?
How can I check it further and maybe fix it?

Comment: What load are you driving?

Comment: "196V" is a voltage measurement, not a current measurement. So does your relay actually pass *current* when it should be off, or is that the *voltage* you're measuring on a floating pin?

Comment: The NO/NC are later connected to a two-way switch that goes to a water heater, so current goes from either NO or NC depending on the switch. So it actually passes current in the situation described. About 10A

Comment: For normal operation, the relay and the physical switch should work like two two-way switches where a change in one off the changes the status of the heater, and it works as expected for the first 40 minutes of operation

Comment: I think you have a bad module.  I recommend get two additional modules and verify the symptom.  If using another module the problem goes away, you know the original module is bad.  If the symptom persists, then the module is not designed or used properly.